# How to insert greek text in my sql db through PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, query-optimization

i'd like to ask a question that's been bothering me for some days now.
I have a mysql db with one table concisted of 38 cells.
Among those cells 2 of them are expecting greek text in them (FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME).
The table and each cell are formatted in utf8-general-ci

Cause the table will be filled with thousand of rows every month, i have a selected to populate it by incerting a csv file created in excel (csv file with commas).

The problem is that it won't allow the greek text to populate those 2 cells, returning the following answer:

## 1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xCC\xC1\xCC\xC1\xD3' for column 'lastname' at row 1

Does anyone have any suggestion on what to do????

Comment: If you haven't seen that post yet, it might help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291184/mysql-general-error-1366-incorrect-string-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin when you choose a table then Import you will se an option like "Charset file" (in greek version of phpMyAdmin it is "Σύνολο χαρακτήρων του αρχείου") you must select utf-8.

If it doesnt work then check your csv file if the greek characters is fine or not then you must check the exporting method.

Comment: Hello again.The excel file, which i convert to csv seperated by commas, is made using arial font. Also at my PhpMyAdmin at the import section i choose the utf-8 charset file option but i still seem to have the same problem. All the numeric data are inserted but those 2 cells that expect greek letters are left blank.

Comment: Try export to csv not from MS Excel but with OpenOffice Excel because MS Excel covert Greek letters to windows-1253 and when it converted to utf-8 from mysql makes chaos.